# Cant use default option more than one time(s)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, timeout

i am trying to use the "timeout" command in a batch script, and it says "ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than one time(s)" and it closes the script after.
Can anyone help me fix this? The code is as follows

```
@echo off
title {REDACTEDPRIVATESTACKOVERFLOW}

echo {REDACTEDPRIVATESTACKOVERFLOW}

timeout /t 3 /timeout 

echo {REDACTEDPRIVATESTACKOVERFLOW}
```

Comment: There's no `/timeout` option for the timeout command; get rid of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just worked for me in the following way:

```
echo "hi"

timeout 3

echo "hi"
```

Comment: i put the flags wrong in the thing
it was timeout /t 3 /nobreak not /timeout